# In CKEditor 5 Change Editor Background Color when Disabled?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

I am using CKEditor 5 with the React framework.
How do I set the background of the editor to dark grey when the editor is disabled?

I am using this CSS to set the background to white when enabled:

```
.ck .ck-editor__main > .ck-editor__editable {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

However, I only want to change the background color value to grey when the child div has `.ck-read-only` but `:has()` has no browser support.

.e.g this does NOT work because browsers do not yet support `:has()`

```
.ck .ck-editor__main > .ck-editor__editable :has(> div.ck-read-only) {
  background: #C3C3C3;
}
```

Implementation of component

```
                <CKEditor
                  disabled={true}
                  editor={Editor}
                  config={{
                    toolbar: [
                      'bold',
                      'italic',
                      'underline',
                      'bulletedList',
                      'numberedList',
                      'link',
                      '|',
                      'imageUpload'
                    ],
                    placeholder: 'Start writing your note'
                  }}
                  onReady={editor => {
                    console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
                  }}
                  onChange={(event, editor) => {
                    const data = editor.getData();
                    console.log({ event, editor, data });
                  }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I made a mistake in my selector and where the classes were attached.  This allows me to set the background color when disabled:

```
.ck .ck-editor__main > .ck-editor__editable.ck-read-only {
  background: #C3C3C3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the CKEditor style by using these classes

**When CKEditor gets Focused**

```
.my-ck-active .ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable, .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners{
  border-color: #16a34a !important;
  //you can add styling here whatever you want

}
```

**When CKEditor gets Error**

```
.my-ck-error .ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable, .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners{
  border-color: red !important;
  //you can add styling here whatever you want

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**//On Focus**

```
.my-ck-active .ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable, .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners{
  border-color: #16a34a !important;
}
```

**//on Error**

```
.my-ck-error .ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable, .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners{
  border-color: red !important;
  //you can add styling here whatever you want

}
```